# AndroidStudio3.0でAndroid Monitorを使用したい

Tags: android, android-studio

題名の通りです。

現在、Android 4.4の端末を使用した開発を実施しているのですが、Android Studio3.0にアップデートした処、Android Monitor が Android Profilerという機能に置き換えられておりデバイスを接続すると「Device not supported」と表示され使用できない状況です。

「Android Profiler requires a device with API 21(Lolipop)」のメッセージが表示されているので、機能がLolipopの端末以降のサポートというのは理解しているのですが、開発対象にKitkat端末が含まれているのでメモリ等のモニターが使用できなくなり困っております。
解消方法をご存知の方がいましたら教えて頂けますでしょうか。

一応、以下のいずれかになるかと思っております。

１．Android Studioをダウングレードする
　->これで解消するのはわかっておりますが、Lolipop以降の端末も開発対象となる為、
　　開発環境自体のダウングレードはしたくないと思っております。
２．Android ProfilerをKitkatで動作可能なようにする
　->難しいでしょうか？ちょっと見当がつきません。
３．代替ツールを利用する
　->何かおすすめのツールがありましたら教えて頂けますでしょうか。

以上です。

Answer (score 3):

Android Device Monitorは表面上取り除かれたように見えますが実際は今もAndroid SDKの中に含まれています
{SDKのインストールパス}/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/moniter を実行するとこのようにAndroid Device Monitorが起動します
初回起動時にPortの設定をするのを忘れないでください

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]